# Java 2D array: summing columns and displaying array problems

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

When the column count and row count are the same, this code works fine. When they differ it throws an exception inside the `columnSum` method.

Here's the error message.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

And here's my code

```
public static void columnSum(int[][] anArray)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int col = 0; col < anArray.length; col++) 
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < anArray[col].length; r++) 
        {
            sum += anArray[r][col];
        }

        System.out.println("Sum of column " + col + " = " + sum);
     }

     System.out.println();
}
```

I have no idea why my code doesn't work when I have more columns than rows or vice versa.

Does anyone have idea?

Comment: ``sum += anArray[col][r]`` I think.

Comment: nope nope~ My program doesn't give me the sum of column 3 when I input 2 for rows and 3 for columns

Comment: my comment is fixing ``ArrayOutOfBoundException`` btw. Because when you input 2 rows and 3 columns, you are calculating sum for 3 rows and 2 columns. Change loops.

Comment: In Java there's compilation and runtime.  I think you mean this is a runtime problem, not a compiler problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sum of columns in a 2 dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302971/sum-of-columns-in-a-2-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

Change
    `sum += anArray[r][col]`

to
    `sum += anArray[col][r]`

This is the reason why it runs when columns & rows are of the same size. When they're of different length, for instance 5 cols & 3 rows, your code will try to access anArray[3][5] in one of the iterations and that elements does not exist, hence the exception.

Comment: nope nope~ My program doesn't give me the sum of column 3 but up to sum of column 2 when I input 2 for rows and 3 for columns. And the calculation is even wrong.

Comment: You're trying to get sum of columns?

Comment: Yes Sir. my method code that gets sum of rows works fine but columnSum  method is giving me headache...

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is in the wrong order. In the external loop you are iterating over the array length and in the internal loop you're iterating over the subarray. Thus, you should access `anArray[col][r];` instead of what you're doing. Your code should be like this:

```
public static void columnSum(int[][] anArray) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < anArray.length; row++) {

        for (int col = 0; col < anArray[row].length; col++) {
            sum += anArray[row][col];

        }

        System.out.println("Sum of row " + row + " = " + sum);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If you really want to sum the column, you should modify your code to:

```
public static void columnSum(int[][] anArray) {
    int sum;
    // Assuming anArray is not empty
    for (int col = 0; col < anArray[0].length; col++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < anArray.length; row++) {   
            sum += anArray[row][col];
        }
         System.out.println("Sum of column " + col + " = " + sum);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Yes I have this for rowSum method and it works perfectly of course. However, I'm trying to get columnSum, not rowSum

Comment: Thanks!! I'm really close to the answer now. Your code seems beautiful and works without errors but it gives me the wrong calculation from sum of column2. It gives me the correct calculation for sum of column 1 though. For example, when my 2D array is [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] (2 rows, 3 columns). The output is Sum of column 1 = 5, Sum of column 2 = 12,
Sum of column 3 = 21. How come do I get this result..? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: my bad. you have to set the value of sum to 0 in each iteration. I edited my answer to do so.